# Keras function like View in Torch

Tags: python, lua, keras, conv-neural-network, torch

I am working on converting some code in Torch and lua to Keras and python. Is there a function in Keras that works like [View](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/simple.md#nn.View) in Torch? **EDIT:** I want to use the function to convert the output from a convolutional layer to proper shape as a input to a fully connected layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually got the answer. I can use [Reshape](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape). 
However, for my case I am using [Flatten](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten) to "flatten" the the shape before passing to a fully connected layer.